# Will I be allowed to enter Spain from a Schengen country as a third-country national resident in that Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, covid-19, spain

I am planning to undertake a trip to Spain and would like to know if I'll be allowed to board the plane and enter given these circumstances:

1. I am a national of a third country, namely Ukraine.
2. I have a residence permit issued by a Schengen country, namely the Czech Republic, and living in that country (actually haven't been outside it for more than a year).
3. I plan to arrive directly from that country.
4. The country is on the red list of the Spanish health ministry.
5. I have been vaccinated against COVID by a vaccine that is recognized in EU and Spain and I have an EU certificate to prove that. The certificate is still valid with a good leeway (vaccination was completed 4 months ago).
6. I know about the requirement to fill out the health form prior to departure.

I tried to read through https://www.mscbs.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm and https://www.spth.gob.es/. However, I could find neither a definitive "yes" nor definitive "no" for exactly such a case.

Unfortunately, my Spanish is way too basic to understand the legislation underlying, so help needed. Also, I understand that quite often official papers don't cover all situations, so anecdotal evidence is welcome, too.

Comment: Did you check the "Map of entry and health control requirements in Spain, dpending on your country of departure"?

Answer (score 3):

The [link you provide](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm) about travel from "third countries" to Spain says:

> Any third-country national will be **subject to denial of entry, for reasons of public order or public health, unless they belong to one of the following categories:**
>
> [...]
>
> k. **Persons with a vaccination certificate**, that the Ministry of Health recognizes for this purpose, after verification by the health authorities, as well as their accompanying minors (under 12 years of age) [...]

(A third-country national means someone who is not a citizen of an EU or EEA country or Switzerland). The same information is on [Reopen EU](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/ESP/7002). So you should not be denied entry for COVID reasons. Of course, the usual disclaimer applies that this information is true now (November 12, 2021) and may change at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that, but the problem is that this is placed under the "entry from third countries" section. I know that common logic says that there should not be more restrictive rules for intra-Schengen traveling than for traveling from outside, however, I have seen enough illogicity in these matters and prefer to check twice.

Comment: As to your note on the misleading use of the term "third countries", this is AFAIK a commonly accepted terminology in EU-speak.

Comment: Yes, I also do not understand why the rule is about the nationality and not about the country of departure. In any case, that page is about all travel to Spain, and it says "If you come from a third country , you must first check if you can travel to Spain", implying that if you do not come from a third country, you do not need to check because you can enter. Travel within the EU is completely open at the moment as far as I know (and any border closures within the EU are usually commented for days in the news).

Comment: You are also on the safe side, as you are vaccinated so you satisfy the requirements for EU and non EU. The question would be somewhat trickier for an unvaccinated, non-EU national traveling within the EU.

Comment: “Third country national” might be jargony or hard to parse but it's not misleading. It's a well established concept and the accepted term for citizens of non EU/EEA countries in EU law and related contexts. It's not a Spanish idiosyncrasy either.

Comment: @Relaxed it is misleading to non-EU readers, which are part of the intended audience of that document. Also, the term [third country](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/pages/glossary/third-country_en) seems to have two different definitions, and it is not clear which one applies when. It would be better if the Spanish document clarified the meaning. Anyway, I removed the "judgemental" part of the answer to avoid distracting from the actual content :)

Comment: @wimi I agree that it can be confusing if you don't know the relevant EU law but it's a subtle concept that is difficult to explain succinctly (and EU law became quite messy with the various opt-outs and ad hoc agreements around the Schengen *acquis*). Sticking with the technical term is less than idea in a public information document but it might actually be the best way not to settle for anything misleading. How did you interpret it when you first read it?

Comment: @Relaxed I am from the EU so I usually don't give much thought to that term when I find it (because it does not apply to me). My evaluation as "misleading" was motivated by a [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39654/24236) we had on Spanish.SE where the asker had indeed been misled by the term :D

Answer (score 2):

This evening, Iberia sent me an email inviting me to fill out a form to see if I'll be admitted to board. The form asked:

- Origin,
- Destination,
- Nationality,
- Residence,
- Vaccination status.

Having filled them as stated in the question, I got the reply saying that I will be allowed to board.

In practical terms I find this satisfactory enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your first link has a link to a [Map of entry and health control requirements in Spain, depending on your country of departure](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spthRequisitosEntradaEspana/home.htm).

As the Czech Republic is considered a risk area within EU/EEA/CH, additional health requirements exist but you should be okay if Czechia's classification and Spanish policy do not change when you travel.

> **Czechia**
>
> Passengers arriving in Spain by air or sea, including those arriving
> in transit to other countries, must complete a Health Control Form
> before departure and obtain their QR to present at boarding and health
> controls on arrival in Spain. You can find more information on the
> website https://spth.gob.es Will open in a new window
>
> In addition to the Health Control Form, passengers must present a
> certificate or document proving vaccination against COVID-19 or a
> negative certificate of a Diagnostic Test of Active Infection or a
> certificate of Recovery after having passed this disease. These
> certificates will be different if they have been issued in a European
> Union country (EU Digital COVID Certificate) or in a third country.
> Children under 12 years of age are exempt from presenting these
> certificates.